# How can I concatenate string to a string as a hex in python?

Tags: python

```
data = "\xAA\x12\xFF\x01\x21\x33"

ser.write(data)
```

This is the original code. How can I concatenate a string to a string (which contains hexa numbers) and use the all as a hexa number to send it as a hexa oder like the second code?

```
var = 21

data = "\xAA\x12\xFF\x01" + var + "\x33"

ser.write(data)
```

Comment: You could use `hex(var)`

Comment: consider adding a Python-2.x tag. I'm pretty sure the way you have it won't work in 3.x

Comment: `chr(var)` is what you're looking for.

Comment: I think you want `var.to_bytes`

Comment: Thanks, the third one works, but I haven't understand why jet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is `hex()` function:

```
>>> var = 21
>>> data = "\xAA\x12\xFF\x01" + hex(var) + "\x33"
>>> data
'\xaa\x12\xff\x01\0x153'
>>>
```

`hex()`  job is to convert an integer number (of any size) to a lowercase hexadecimal string prefixed with “0x”.

**EDIT**:
I noticed you need the backslash to keep the formatting, so `chr()` will return the hexa value with the backslash.

```
>>> chr(var)
'\x15'
>>> hex(var)
'0x15'
```

`chr(i)` returns a string of one character whose ASCII code is the integer i.